# Get Product Count in a single Category in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to show how many active products are in a single category in Magento 1.8.

I need to display a few choosen categorys in a .phtml file and want to display how many products are in those categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all products count with visibility = Catalog search, Catalog and status = Enabled

```
<?php
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3); // 3 is the category id here
$_product = $_category->getProductCollection();
$_product->setVisibility(array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG));
$_product->addFieldToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
echo $_product->count();
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2, we should take a look at this:

vendor/magento/module-catalog-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/Category/ProductsCount.php

```
    $productsCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
    $productsCollection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
    $productsCollection = $this->stockProcessor->process($productsCollection, $this->searchCriteria, []);

    return $productsCollection->getSize();
```